# Run time exception while trying to json serialize a 'val' or 'lazy val' Tuple field in grand parent Trait, in scala using json4s

Tags: scala, json4s

I ran into a run time exception while serializing a case class, which extends a trait, which in turn extends another grandparent trait.

**Problem occurs only when the grandparent trait contains a val or lazy val, which is a tuple.**

```
trait Trait0 {
  def a: Int

  lazy val b: (Int, Int) = (1, 2)
  // also errors if "val"
  // executes if "def" or just a simple type
}

trait Trait1 extends Trait0

case class Test(a: Int) extends Trait1

object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import org.json4s._
    import org.json4s.native.Serialization.write

    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats


    println(write(Test(1)))
  }
}
```

RunTime Exception I get is

> Exception in thread "main" org.json4s.package$MappingException: Can't
>   find field b from class com.adobe.formfactory.generator.Test  at
>   org.json4s.reflect.package$.fail(package.scala:95)    at
>   org.json4s.reflect.ScalaSigReader$.read$1(ScalaSigReader.scala:43)    at
>   org.json4s.reflect.ScalaSigReader$.$anonfun$readField$3(ScalaSigReader.scala:47)
>     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)     at
>   org.json4s.reflect.ScalaSigReader$.read$1(ScalaSigReader.scala:47)    at
>   org.json4s.reflect.ScalaSigReader$.readField(ScalaSigReader.scala:49)
>     at
>   org.json4s.reflect.Reflector$ClassDescriptorBuilder.$anonfun$fields$3(Reflector.scala:69)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:52)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:227)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
>     at
>   org.json4s.reflect.Reflector$ClassDescriptorBuilder.fields(Reflector.scala:68)
>     at
>   org.json4s.reflect.Reflector$ClassDescriptorBuilder.properties(Reflector.scala:85)
>     at
>   org.json4s.reflect.Reflector$ClassDescriptorBuilder.result(Reflector.scala:184)
>     at org.json4s.reflect.Reflector$.createDescriptor(Reflector.scala:53)
>     at
>   org.json4s.reflect.Reflector$.$anonfun$describe$1(Reflector.scala:48)
>     at org.json4s.reflect.package$Memo.apply(package.scala:36)  at
>   org.json4s.reflect.Reflector$.describe(Reflector.scala:48)    at
>   org.json4s.Extraction$.decomposeObject$1(Extraction.scala:118)    at
>   org.json4s.Extraction$.internalDecomposeWithBuilder(Extraction.scala:228)
>     at org.json4s.Extraction$.decomposeWithBuilder(Extraction.scala:64)
>     at org.json4s.native.Serialization$.write(Serialization.scala:43)   at
>   org.json4s.native.Serialization$.write(Serialization.scala:37)    at
>   com.adobe.formfactory.generator.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)     at
>   com.adobe.formfactory.generator.Main.main(Main.scala)

**Scala2.12.3

JDK1.8

json4s-native 3.5.3**

I am guessing json4s isn't traversing up the super chain for tuples or other composite objects ?

If it were a case of providing custom serializer, the error, would mention that certain type cant be serialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is an existing bug since v3.4

https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues/221